# Jquery ajax call doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax and jquery to submit a form when a user checks a checkbox. Then it should submit an ajax call to an order.php page.

This is the javascript used

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#statusform").on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
        $("#statusform").submit();
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#statusform').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'order.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&action=changestatus',
            datatype: "json",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data["json"]);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And heres the form

```
<form id="statusform">
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="betalt" id="betalt" data-on-text="Betalt" data-off-text="Ikke betalt" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch" <?php if ($row['betalt']) {echo "checked";}?>>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="leveret" id="leveret" data-on-text="Leveret" data-off-text="Ikke leveret" data-wrapper-class="custom-size-flipswitch" <?php if ($row['leveret']) {echo "checked";}?>>
</form>
```

Everything works fine on a desktop pc browser, but when tried on a google chrome mobile browser on my iphone, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Do any of you guys have any ideas?

Comment: have u tried to use JqueryMobile ?

Comment: I do use jquery mobile for the flipswitch and such. But what can it do for me in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I found my answer...somewhat atleast.

The problem was that in Chrome on IOS. When you click a an achor link ("a href") that for instance points to "Order.php". It would enter the URL as http://website.com/#/order.php - Which causes the AJAX calls to stop working for some reason.

If I removed the hash it works as intended.

I believe the hashtag is cause by jquery mobile as the link was in a jquery mobile tab control and was a jquery mobile listview. On Safari (iOS), Chrome (PC) and IExplorer (PC) everything works as intended and the link doesn't add the hashtag.

Does anybody know why chrome does this? And perhaps how to circumvent the problem?